# How can we use local Chrome's cookies to login using Selenium?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, cookies, webdriver

I'm trying to create a test suite that does a login to Google's Gmail website with Selenium.
The problem is that Selenium opens a new Chrome window (Like incognito mode) with no cookies.
My code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://hangouts.google.com/")

elem = driver.find_element_by_id("gb_70")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

elem2 = driver.find_element_by_id("identifierId")
elem2.send_keys("mygmail@gmail.com")
elem2.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(2)

elem3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='whsOnd zHQkBf']")
elem3.send_keys("myPass")
elem3.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

From what I read on the internet it is possible to create 2 sessions, one for storing the cookies and the second for using those cookies.
But this is not something that I'm looking for, I need it to use the cookies that Chrome store.

I tried to read the Chrome's cookies manually (from APPDATA) but it seems that it is encrypted by the browser.

Comment: Also, provide your code.

Answer (score 11):

When you need cookies from session to session there is another way to do it, use the Chrome options user-data-dir in order to use folders as profiles, I run:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=selenium") 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("www.google.com")
```

You can do here the logins that check for human interaction, I do this and then the cookies I need now every-time I start the Webdriver with that folder everything is in there. You can also manually install the Extensions and have them in every session.
Secon time I run, all the cookies are there:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=selenium") 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("www.google.com") #Now you can see  the cookies, the settings, Extensions and the logins done in the previous session are present here
```

The advantage is you can use multiple folders with different settings and cookies, Extensions without the need to load, unload cookies, install and uninstall Extensions, change settings, change logins via code, and thus no way to have the logic of the program break, etc Also this is faster than having to do it all by code.

Comment: Cannot use chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=selenium")  and chrome_options.add_argument("--headless") in the same test. Why is that?

Comment: You saved my life. I have tried many ways to store and restore cookeis, but all failed. This solution is so simple and it really works.

Comment: that way cookies are encrypted :( Is there another solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following steps:

1. Login as typical Gmail user and save cookies to the file (Script 1) under URL like (https://www.google.com).
2. Login using cookies: open the browser in the needed domain (https://www.google.com) and load cookies, refresh the page (Script 2).

From your code:

1. I think you need to add a wait after logging in.
2. Check that cookies are set (Developer Tools -> Application -> Cookies).

PS: If you still have the same issue after -> change your URL to "https://accounts.google.com".

Hope it helps you!

Comment: You rewrote what I wrote, This is not something that I want because I want to do login to multiple accounts and Google asks for a phone number

Comment: @KaramJaber, you need to disable 2-factor authentication for logging in and getting cookies. After that, you can enable it.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: you can set the cookies for accounts.gmail.com

1. navigate to google.com and then set relevant cookies
2. navigate to accounts.google.com and set the relevant cookies (supposed to be different cookies)
3. navigate again to gmail.com

**Why?**

The problem with Gmail is that you are redirected to "mail.google.com" when you try to login, so you must have the cookies of this different domain in your session.

Selenium webdriver's `add_cookie` method won't allow you to set cookies for domain A if your browser is in domain B (in Gmail case, mail.google.com is A and google.com is B).
The only way to get it done with Selenium, is to navigate to mail.google.com and then set the cookies when you get to this page, before being redirected, and then start over. It's problematic, because if you navigate to mail.google.com you will be redirected immediately so you can't set cookies.

There are 3 ways I would try:

1. Try to stop the redirection somehow, so you can set the cookies for mail.google.com and then start over.
2. Try to find another webdriver that will allow you to set cookies
3. Use selenium web-driver with cookies file or user data directory
4. Change the code of selenium webdriver to allow you to set cookies (https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/1953#c4)