# Selenium: Get all visible text in Tableau view

Tags: python, selenium, tableau-api

I am trying to get all visible text from a Tableau view using Selenium. I define all visible text as any text that can be searched using any browser's search functionality (i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>).

I have already searched many other answers to related questions but none of them worked for my case. I tried the top answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947579/getting-all-visible-text-from-a-webpage-using-selenium). It doesn't work for me from the very start since my `browser.page_source` contains no visible text. Here are the contents of my `browser.page_source`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns:ng="" xmlns:tb=""><head><style type="text/css">@charset "UTF-8";[ng\:cloak],[ng-cloak],[data-ng-cloak],[x-ng-cloak],.ng-cloak,.x-ng-cloak,.ng-hide:not(.ng-hide-animate){display:none !important;}ng\:form{display:block;}.ng-animate-shim{visibility:hidden;}.ng-anchor{position:absolute;}</style><meta charset="UTF-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><meta name="viewport" content="width=1024, maximum-scale=1.3"><meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=434633927"><meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"><script>var BuildId = '9qu3thidy901n388pewixusor';
var StaticAssetsUrlPrefix = '';</script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vizportal.css?9qu3thidy901n388pewixusor"><script src="/javascripts/api/tableau-2.1.0.min.js?9qu3thidy901n388pewixusor"></script><script src="vizportalMinLibs.js?9qu3thidy901n388pewixusor"></script><script src="vizportal.min.js?9qu3thidy901n388pewixusor"></script></head><body class="tb-body"><div ng-app="VizPortalRun" id="ng-app" tb-window-resize="" class="tb-app ng-scope"><!-- uiView:  --><div ui-view="" class="tb-app-inner ng-scope"></div><span class="ng-isolate-scope"><div class="tb-toaster tb-enable-selection" data-reactid=".0"></div></span><script type="text/ng-template" id="inline_stackedElement.html"><div tb-window-resize tb-left="left" tb-top="top" tb-right="right" tb-bottom="bottom" tb-visible="visible" class="tb-absolute"></div></script><!-- ngRepeat: stackedElement in stackedElements --><span props="stackedComponentsProps" class="ng-isolate-scope"><div data-reactid=".1"></div></span></div></body></html>
```

Also tried the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18336956/get-visible-text-of-page-with-selenium-webdriver). Obviously, this didn't work as there's no text inside the `body` as you can see in the page source above.

What is the correct way to get the visible text in these circumstances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I keep saying `pages_source` gets the source but is not the same, `Inspect Element` inspects the [`DOM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model), the source page although is practically the original seed page for the [`DOM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model), the [`DOM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) can  dynamically change and usually changes by JS code, 
 sometimes quite dramatically. Also you will notice that `Inspect Element` shows the shadow elements which the source show not.

To see how dramatic is the difference visit `chrome://settings/` and click `Inspect element` and then look at the `View page source` and compare.

So you need to take what you need from the [`DOM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) to do that you could iterate through all the tags and get `textContent`
This is the JS snippet:

```
page =""; var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*"); for (tag of all) page = page + tag.textContent;
```

or in selenium/python:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("http://ranprieur.com")
pagetext = driver.execute_script('page =""; var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*"); for (tag of all) page = page + tag.textContent; return page;')
```

[image]

Comment: I know that page source doesn't show any dynamic content, just didn't know any other way to do this. 

I tried to execute your code in Python and got the following exception: `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Expected token 'in'","request":{"headers": ... *lots of header info*... }} Screenshot: available via screen`

Comment: @MaxLawnboy Run `Ctrl+Shift+J` Try pasting  `page =""; var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*"); for (tag of all) page = page + tag.textContent; console.log(page);` Do you get the text you want ?

Comment: @MaxLawnboy I think the error might not be related to my code I ran the code see update and for me it works just fine

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I get the expected result if I run your script from the browser console. I guess the error I got when accessing the webpage using Selenium webdriver is due to authentication issues. Will need to figure that out next. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @MaxLawnboy You could use profile folders and login manually, and login will be kept in cookies etc,  see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48873573/1577343