# How to open a URL in Chrome and Get it's content?

Tags: python

This code opens a URL in my default browser (chrome)

```
import webbrowser

a_website = "https://www.example.com/"

# Open url in a new window of the default browser, if possible
#webbrowser.open_new(a_website)

# Open url in a new page (“tab”) of the default browser, if possible
webbrowser.open_new_tab(a_website)
```

Now, I want to get it's content also, like:

```
content = webbrowser.open_new_tab(a_website)
```

If possible, also close the new table opened using Python once, I get the content.

Note: My Chrome browser has cookies for that specific page. So the content will be different, If I do not open the web browser and read it from there. urllib won't work, i guess.

Here is my other code, but it opens a new chrome driver without the cookies

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
chromedriver = "C:/Users/Kamal Chhirang/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get(openthisurl)
time.sleep(10)
with open('page.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(driver.page_source)
```

Comment: Search for "selenium" and go from there.

Comment: I did, but it opens a chrome driver without my chrome browser cookies

Comment: Your best bet isn't to rely on cookies that happen to be in your browser today, but to get appropriate cookies in an automated way. If they're related to login, then log in with Selenium (or `requests` or whatever).

Comment: I need to enter Captcha login. That's the problem. But in my main browser, One I login, I don't need to login again for 30 minutes.

Comment: I am trying to book an appointment for my VISA, but all slots are booked. So From last 2 weeks, I am checking the url manually every 5 minutes. :(((((

Comment: You don't need selenium, just use `requests`. Copy the cookies from your browser, or do a log in step from your script to get the cookies.

Comment: The Captcha is actually easy, I know some machine learning. I can probably crack it. But for now, I am good with the automated checking for 30 minutes per step

Comment: Okay thanks, I will try

Comment: You could also probably just write a JS snippet and paste it into the console on the appropriate tab.

Comment: Hmmm, makes sense. But can I notify myself by sending email or by a beeep loud sound? If something changes? Using JS on console?

Comment: Is there not an  API that would let you accomplish this without having to resort to screen scraping?

Comment: I need to hover a button to check the "Result" that I want. Maybe there is a Windows app. But the session is limited to only 30 minutes. If I get Python solution for this problem. Then I can also make a Captcha cracker program, and it checks the result for me 24/7. So trying to look for Python solution first, as it will be perfect

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48869775/how-can-we-use-local-chromes-cookies-to-login-using-selenium for how to use your browser cookies in selenium