# How to get token from application cookies part by using java selenium

Tags: java, api, selenium-webdriver, testng, rest-assured

[image]
How to fetch the token from the browser by using java selenium for using it in rest assured

How to write code, for elements we use find elements but here what we can use to get the token

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we use local Chrome's cookies to login using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48869775/how-can-we-use-local-chromes-cookies-to-login-using-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple, see https://www.guru99.com/handling-cookies-selenium-webdriver.html

**Code sample:**

```
package tests;

import java.util.Set;

import org.openqa.selenium.Cookie;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import selenium.ChromeDriverSetup;

public class CookieValueTest extends ChromeDriverSetup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        WebDriver driver = startChromeDriver(); // wrapped driver init
        driver.get("https://www.stackoverflow.com");
        Set<Cookie> allCookies = driver.manage().getCookies();
        for (Cookie cookie: allCookies) {
            System.out.println("Cookie domain: " + cookie.getDomain());
            System.out.println("Cookie name: " + cookie.getName());
            System.out.println("Cookie value: " + cookie.getValue());
        }
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
Cookie domain: .stackoverflow.com
Cookie name: prov
Cookie value: 3dad3e4b-5cdd-6e2b-8890-bcca530e2f67
```